# Android Studio Project broken after adding Google Volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I added Google volley to my app project. However, now I can no longer compile it. When trying to Gradle sync I constantly get the following error message:

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: /Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk
```

Open Android SDK Manager

I opened the SDK Manager and installed everything that was requested. However, I'm still getting the same error.

I did the following:

1. git clone volley project
2. In Studio: File -> New -> New Module -> Import Gradle Project -> selected volley folder
3. Added `compile project('volley')` to the `settings.gradle` in the dependency part

Comment: hi @toom did you find the solution ? I m too facing same problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: In my `build.gradle (Module: app)` I added the following line `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'` in the `dependencies { ... }` section. This will download the appropriate library automatically. Very convenient ;)

Comment: Though it is not official but its really convenient .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'`

it means that the version of volley you imported has as dependency Android-22 (Android 5.1.1). Open the Android SDK manager and install it. After this error should disapper

Comment: Please read what I wrote: `I opened the SDK Manager and installed everything that was requested`

Comment: my bad. Is `/Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk` the correct sdk folder ?

Comment: Yeah, it is. That's odd although I installed 22 an `ls` on the console in `sdk/platforms` says: `android-10/ android-17/ android-21/ android-23/`

Comment: that's odd. Are you using linux? Can you check where it did get downloaded ? `find . -iname android-22`, should do it

Comment: Okay, appearently the SDK Manager downloaed the wrong version 23 instead of 22. I downloaed 22 separately. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google's official volley library in my projects by the following steps:

1. Git clone, of course :)
2. Copy & paste its `android` folder into `\app\src\main\java\com` folder path of my project
3. If my project `compileSdkVersion 23`, then add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` into `build.gradle` file

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, @Toom mentioned to use

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'
}
```

This workaround was very useful at the time. Maybe there were many bugs in the official back in the day, I don't know, because I used this. Yet, it appears that this has been deprecated at 1.0.19 (Readme was updated in 2017). The repo can be found at https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley . Today, the official is at 1.1.0 and documentation can be found at https://developer.android.com/training/volley/ . Other answers explain how to use this in your project.