# 'android' command on Mac OS X shows no output

Tags: android, macos, cordova, console, command

I've installed Android Studio today on Mac OS X, and the 'android' command in the terminal shows no output, regardless of parameters. That's how it looks like:

```
bash-3.2$ android             
bash-3.2$
```

As I understand, echo $? shows the returning error code? Well it's 0 after running 'android'.

I was not able to find any manual on this command, because it's named "android", and Google finds all sorts of Android-related things when you look for it. Why I need this command - I believe it's the culprit of Cordova failing to build an Android app; it continues to request me to install target "android-22" even after I installed it. I read somewhere that 'android list targets' should print currently installed targets, and I suspect that Cordova sees its empty output and thinks there are no targets installed. Location of 'android' script is correct, it's in the "/Users//Library/Android/sdk/tools/android"

Will appreciate any advice. I failed to find any information on such a problem.

Comment: about the [android-22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043625/android-studio-project-broken-after-adding-google-volley/33043647#comment53908298_33043647)

Comment: @adarsh if it wasn't in PATH, it would say something like "unknown command 'android'"

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue; it was some glitch with Java installation - maybe related to the new El Capitan 'rootless' protection, I'm not sure. But after I disabled 'rootless' and reinstalled JDK, 'android' starts up properly, and Cordova builds and runs the app.

Unfortunately, I do not know what exactly was wrong with Java, and is it really 'rootless' to blame. I did not make a backup point that would allow me to compare. Still, I hope someone will find this useful.